# Can we post/publish some thing on our g+ wall using moment.insert method?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I want to post/publish some content on my g+ wall using java script. I can use share button. But my requirement is with out showing the share popup, some content should be be posted on my wall. For that can i use moment insert method google API.I have tried I got some response but nothing is posted on my wall. Here is my code please check it. Thanks in advance.

```
gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1',function(){
        url = "https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing";
        var payload = {
              "type":"http:\/\/schema.org\/AddAction",
              "startDate": "2012-10-31T23:59:59.999Z"
            };
            if (url != undefined){
              payload.target = {
                'url' : url
              };
            }else{
            payload.target = {
              "id" : "a-special-report-old-foes",
              "image" : "http:\/\/www.google.com\/s2\/static\/images\/GoogleyEyes.png",
              "description" : "Testing Testing Testing",
              "type" : "http:\/\/schema.org\/AddAction",
              "name":"An example of AddAction"

            };
          }
          gapi.client.plus.moments.insert(
              {  'userId' : 'me',
                 'collection' : 'vault',
                 'resource' : payload
              }).execute(function(result){
                  console.log(result);
              });

       });
```

And Im getting this response

```
Object {kind: "plus#moment", type: "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", target: Object, result: Object, startDate: "2012-10-31T23:59:59.999Z"…}
id: "Eg0xMzUxNzI3OTk5OTk5GJLK-KbPiOfVxgEpCHuQgEQo0AkyAhAUQgcY3ufnoLwG"
kind: "plus#moment"
result: Object
startDate: "2012-10-31T23:59:59.999Z"
target: Object
type: "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Moments aren't posted directly to the stream. As it says on https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities:

> With a user's permission, individual app activities can appear on their Google+ profile, visible to people they choose to share with...

Your moment "vault" shows up in your profile under the "Apps" section. Clicking on an app there will show you the moments that have been logged. From here, users do have the option to share it to their stream, but this requires a specific action on their part.

There is no way to do what you want - Google+ is designed to require the user to explicitly approve anything that shows up in their stream.